# Modifying PDO INSERTS to enhance lastInsertId usage

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm using MySQL PDO with auto-commit disabled.

So I have the following code:

```
    try
    {
        $db_connect_handle->beginTransaction();
        $pdo_stmt_obj = self::$db_connect_handle->prepare($query_sql_str);
        $pdo_stmt_obj->execute();
        $db_connect_handle->commit();
    }
    catch (database_exception $e)
    {
        $db_connect_handle->rollBack();
        print_r($e);
    }

    echo $db_connect_handle->lastInsertId();
```

The `INSERT` query works ok. However, I don't get a value for `$db_connect_handle->lastInsertId()`. I read in the PHP manual that I should use `lastInsertId` before I commit, but I have a central Query script and I wouldn't want to do any SQL Query classification prior to committing the transaction.

Then I changed my code to this:

```
    try
    {
        $pdo_stmt_obj = self::$db_connect_handle->prepare($query_sql_str.'; COMMIT;');
        $pdo_stmt_obj->execute();
    }
    catch (database_exception $e)
    {
        $db_connect_handle->rollBack();
        print_r($e);
    }

    echo $db_connect_handle->lastInsertId();
```

And voila! now I get a value for `$db_connect_handle->lastInsertId()`.

My question is, will this affect the performance of the `INSERT`, and also will the `$db_connect_handle->rollBack()` work?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no transaction, rollBack won't work. Also in documentation, it says if there is no transaction, rollBack throws exception.

For only one query, you already don't need transaction. If query failed, nothing changed in database, also means there is nothing to roll back. Thus, there won't be any performance difference.